# Putting an image below the nav bar bootstrap and css WITHOUT it being overlapped by text

Tags: html, css, image, bootstrap-4

I am simply trying to place an image directly UNDER the navbar. I DO NOT want the nav bar text to overlap the image in any way.

No matter what I do in my code the image stays locked to the end of the navbar. It will not go into its own separate row BELOW the nav bar.

I have tried putting it in its own div, section, p, ul, li, and nothing works.

Is there a way to adjust the image in another contianer, without using the break tags.

```
    <nav id="mainNavbar" class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-md fixed-top">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">TEXT</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navLinks" aria-label="toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggle-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navLinks">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link">Projects</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
                 </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<body>
    <section>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <img class="img-thumbnail rounded-circle" src="/Users/admin/Pictures/img.jpg" alt="img">
                </div>
```

Comment: is `.fixed-top` necessary for you?. `fixed-top` makes `position:fixed` for tag `<nav>` so `image` obviously stack to nav. Remove it and try. If `fixed-top` is compulsory for you then give `margin-top`  to the `image`.

Comment: The only thing is I would like to keep the nav bar fixed to the top so that when I scroll down I still have access to the navbar. I want the image to be in the body of my text right below the nav bar

Comment: Then you can use `padding-top:50px` property for `body`. Or else you can use `sticky-top` for `nav` but it is not compatible for all browser.

Comment: Okay I kept the fixed top, but I got rid of the <br> tags in my html and adding padding to my body prop in css and that seem to achieve my goal. Thank you!

Comment: Okay, I will post my answer in the answer section in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fixed-top` makes `nav` to be `position: fixed`, So the vertical height can't be filled. If any further tags are added, those tags will stack to the `nav`.

To overcome this situation use `padding-top` of approximate calculation of `nav` height say `50px`. So applying this value to the further tag in your case `<body style='padding-top:50px'>`

Or else we can use `sticky-top`, but it is not compatible for all browser yet

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use position sticky instead of position fixed for your navbar

Comment: The problem Im having with sticky is that is doesnt allow the navbar to continue being displayed at the top when you scroll down so that you can access the nav bar even if you have scrolled to the bottom of the page.